# Visit localhost(wordpress blog) from Internet with correct data paths instead of "http://localhost/..."

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost, portforwarding

I am trying to test my different mobile media queries on my devices through the internet to my localhost wordpress installation.

The forwarding works good, I can see the server and the HTML structure gets displayed but the rest not. The data paths of the Images, CSS files and other important files is still

`"http://localhost/..."` instead of `"XXX.XXX.X.XXX(the actual ip)"`

I dont want to change the wordpress database so my question is there a way to get rid of the localhost part in my paths and replace it with the actual ip?

I tried it with an .htaccess file but that was more confusing than it helps...

**System Details:**

- WIN 8 (ACER)
- dlink router with forwarded port(TCP/UDP: 25565)
- XAMPP 3.2.1
- Apache Port 80, 443

thx in advance for any help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

To change the path *without editing the database*, during testing edit `wp-config.php` and add

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://your-ip');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://your-ip');
```

before the

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

line. Once you're done testing, just remove those two lines.

<sub>(Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php)</sub>